# How to create and manage just enough actors to maximise CPU usage in Swift?

Tags: swift, concurrency, actor

I often find myself having to perform lots of operations on a single resource, e.g. resizing an image to lots of different resolutions. When the resource in question is `Sendable` (which for example is the case with `CGImage`), I can use `withTaskGroup` and create a child task for each operation I need to perform, which maximises the CPU usage (as long as the `Sendable` resource in question doesn't perform its own synchronisation to prevent concurrent operations).

Sometimes, however, the resource is *not* `Sendable` (e.g. `CGPDFPage`). In these cases I might do one of either three things:

1. Simply avoid the use of tasks altogether, and just perform the operations I need to perform within a standard loop on a single thread.
2. Wrap the non-sendable resource within an `actor`, and continue to use `withTaskGroup` to create child tasks for each operation I want to perform (which would call an isolated method on the actor).
3. Use `withTaskGroup` to create child tasks for each operation I want to perform, initialising a fresh copy of the resource within each task.

**Methods 1 and 2** have basically the same result: even by using `withTaskGroup` in method 2, everything will still happen synchronously because of the isolated nature of actors.

**Method 3** does allow me to maximise the CPU, but it requires initialising the resource every time I want to perform an operation on it, which might be thousands of times, and there can be a significant cost to initialising that resource (such as loading it from the filesystem). Even so, despite this added cost, it might still complete the operations faster (if not in particularly optimised way).

---

Ideally, I want to create *just enough* resources/actors to maximise CPU usage (e.g. if the machine has eight cores, I'd probably want to create eight resources, each one wrapped within an instance of an actor). Then, I'd do the thousands of operations, creating a task for each one. In each task it would pick an idle actor from the "actor pool" to perform the operation on.

Is this the best way of doing what I'm trying to do? If so, how can I effectively manage the so-called "actor pool", ensuring that it creates only the number of resources required?

Comment: I haven't needed to do much with actors, so I don't think I'm qualified to write an actual answer, but I would think you could do it with a circular buffer with the same number of actors as your cores, where you send the work to be done to the circular buffer, and it keeps track of which actor to forward the work to next.   As for the number of cores `ProcessInfo.processInfo.processorCount` will give you that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding “maximizing CPU usage”, you may know this already, but Swift concurrency has a “cooperative thread pool”, which will maximize CPU usage while exceeding the device’s capabilities. So, if your processing task is synchronous, just add tasks to your task group, and it will avoid thread explosion, but also fully utilize your CPU.

Regarding your question on various approaches, it is very hard to answer this question in the abstract. There is a certain amount of overhead introduced by concurrency. The goal is to maximize the amount of computational work done in the concurrent task as compared to the initialization and synchronization overhead.

Regarding your single vs. multithreaded question (i.e., option 1), we must recognize that there are some processes that simply do not lend themselves to parallelism, for which the gains from concurrency are not sufficient to offset the overhead it introduces. The goal is to perform as much uncontended computational work in each task added to the group, and limit the synchronization (the actor isolated work) to the minimum.

Regarding the multi-actor approach, I am hard-pressed to imagine a scenario where that will yield benefits over a single actor. Our goal is to minimize the synchronization as much as possible, and adding two tiers of synchronization seems like it would only make it worse (and more complicated). I would probably pursue striding before two-tier synchronization pattern (e.g., rather than 10,000 tasks building one page each, perhaps 100 tasks building 100 pages each).

But if you are dealing with a combination of low-computational complexity with high-contention of shared resources, a single-threaded solution might actually end up being faster. Sometimes you just have to do it both ways and benchmark it before you can be sure.

We probably need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to assist you further.